# How do I send an email with an attachment in CakePHP 2.0?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm trying to send an email with an attachment using CakePHP 2.0.

The file is submitted by the user via a form.

So far I have:

```
App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');
$email = new CakeEmail();
$email->attachments = array($this->data['Opportunity']['resume_file']['tmp_name']);
$email->viewVars(array('name' => $this->data['Opportunity']['name']));
$email->template('application')
    ->emailFormat('html')
    ->to(TEST_CONTACT)
    ->from(EMAIL_CONTACT)
    ->subject('New application received')
    ->send();
```

The email sends and looks fine, but there is no attachment.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some reason CakePHP won't do attachments unless you state the
filePaths first.

I have the same problem and I did not manage to find many answer to
this question. It took me a while to solve the problem,  to clarify,
I got it working by

```
$this->Email->filePaths  = array('/home/username/');
       $this->Email->attachments =array('article_button.png');
$this->Email->to      = 'em...@email.co.uk';
    $this->Email->subject = 'Something';
    $this->Email->replyTo = $client['Client']['email'];
    $this->Email->from    = $client['Client']['email'];
    $this->Email->sendAs  = 'html';

    if($this->Email->send('Testing', null, null)){
      die('Email Sent!');
    }else{
      die('Failed to send email');
    }
```

http://groups.google.com/group/cake-php/browse_thread/thread/93a9c9467733fe38?pli=1

Comment: I never had issues with the attachment path. strange

Comment: Thanks for this, but I haven't been able to make it work. When I print out the path to the temporary file, I get /home/content/57/4087557/tmp/phpblahblah - so I should have $email->filePaths= array('/home/content/57/4087557/tmp/'), right?

Answer (score 2):

Put below script in **AppController.php**

```
 function sendMailWithAttachment($template = null, $to_email = null, $from_email = null, $subject = null, $contents = array()) {
        $from_email = 'noreply@xyz.com';
        $email = new CakeEmail();
        $result = $email->template($template, 'default')
                ->emailFormat('html')
                ->to($to_email)
                ->from($from_email)
                ->subject($subject)
            ->attachments('your-server-path/filename.extenstion')
                ->viewVars($contents);
        if ($email->send('default')) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

After that just call the method sendMailWithAttachment() in any controller like

```
$this->sendMailWithAttachment('tmpl', 'test@abc.com','noreply@xyz.com', 'Subject', $tmpl_DATA_IN_ARRAY);
```