# CakePHP : send email with attachment via console

Tags: cakephp, console, email-attachments

I'm trying to send out emails with the CakePHP 1.3 email component via console/cron.
The emails are sent out & received, but without the attachment.

When done via form, the emails are sent with the attachment successfully.
I have tried adding
    **$this->Email->filePaths**,
(from [How do I send an email with an attachment in CakePHP 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10045719/how-do-i-send-an-email-with-an-attachment-in-cakephp-2-0))
but the attachments are still not being sent.

My code is as below :

```
$email =& new EmailComponent();
$email->reset();
$email->initialize($controller);        
$email->delivery = $emailConfigurations['delivery'];        
$email->from = $emailConfigurations['from'];
$email->replyTo = $emailConfigurations['replyTo'];
$email->return = $emailConfigurations['return'];
$email->template = 'default';
$email->sendAs = $emailConfigurations['sendAs'];

if (strcasecmp($email->delivery, 'smtp') == 0) {
    $email->smtpOptions = array(
        'timeout' => $emailConfigurations['smtpTimeout'],
        'port' => $emailConfigurations['smtpPort'],
        'host' => $emailConfigurations['smtpHost'],
        'username' => $emailConfigurations['smtpUsername'],
        'password' => $emailConfigurations['smtpPassword']
    );
}

$email->to = $newEmail['mail_to'];
$email->subject = $newEmail['message_title'];

if ($newEmail['attachment_name'] && $newEmail['attachment_tmp']) {
    $attachedFilePath = WWW_ROOT . 'files' . DS .  'email_attachments' . DS ;
    $attachedFile = $newEmail['attachment_tmp'];

    $this->Email->filePaths  = array($attachedFilePath); 
    $this->Email->attachments = array($attachedFile);
}

if($email->send($newEmail['message'])){
    $this->out(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')." Email sent : ".$newEmail['id']);
} else {
    $this->out(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')." Email not sent : ".$newEmail['id']);
}
```

So, basically my question is how do i get the emails sent out with attachment when I run the shell script via console/cron.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you're queuing and sending emails via the console, you may have some interest in this plugin. It may cut down on some of your work. https://github.com/jeremyharris/queue_email/

Comment: I shall take a look at your plugin once I get back to the cron jobs. Shall update the results here once done. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the trailing `DS` from your path list, as Cake doesn't trim it:

```
$attachedFilePath = WWW_ROOT . 'files' . DS .  'email_attachments';
```

Comment: Have you tried just using a full attachment path instead of using the `Email->filePaths` var? Like `$this->Email->attachments = array(WWW_ROOT . 'files' . DS .  'email_attachments' . DS . $newEmail['attachment_tmp'])`. Also, verify the files exist in that location with `file_exists()`.

Comment: Yes, I have & the file indeed exists. But still no attachments in the emails. Looking forward to try out your plugin & hoping that would sort the issue (& hopefully shed a light on what the real reason is for mine not working).

Comment: Hi, the project has been cancelled & I have moved on. But if anybody has an answer to this, would appreciate the knowledge. Thanks