# Cakephp Sendgrid not attaching attachments

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0, mailgun

Here is the code I'm using in `cakephp` function for `mailgun`.

```
 function sendemail($to,$subject,$template_name,$variables){
                $this->autoRender=false;
                App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');
                $Email =new CakeEmail('mailgun');
                $Email->from(array($from => $from_name));
                $Email->to($to);
                $Email->subject($subject);
                $Email->attachments(array(
                                'file.csv' => array(
                                    'file' => WWW_ROOT . 'csv' . DS . 'data_28122018_2211.csv',
                                    'mimetype' => 'text/csv',
                                    'contentId' => 'my-unique-id'
                                )
                            ));
                $Email->template($template_name,null);
                $Email->emailFormat('html');
                $Email->viewVars($variables);
                $Email->send();
            }
```

And getting response of the attachment as below, But no attachment attached in mail.
Please help.

> --rel-732f894bea31c14ce42d0ab7d93adc77 Content-Type: text/csv Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 Content-ID: Content-Disposition: inline; filename="file.csv" IklEIiwiU3RhdHVzIiwiQ2FsbFN0YXR1cyIsIlJlc3BvbnNlIiwiVXJsIiwiU291cmNlIiwiV2lk Z2V0IiwiTGl2ZSBPciBTY2hlZHVsZWQiLCJDcmVkaXRzIFVzZWQiLCJMZWFkIiwiQWdlbnQiLCJE ZXBhcnRtZW50IiwiRHluYW1pYyBOdW1iZXIiLCJIb3VyIiwiTWludXRlIiwiU2Vjb25kIiwiRHVy YXRpb24iLCJEYXRlIiwiVGltZSIsIlNjaGVkdWxlZCBEYXRlIiwiU2NoZWR1bGVkIFRpbWUiLCJS ZWNvcmQiLCJJUCBBZGRyZXNzIiwiR0EgQ2xpZW50IElEIiwiQnJvd3NlciIsIkRldmljZSIsIkxv Y2F0aW9uIiwiQ291bnRyeSIsIlZpc2l0IE9uIiwiQWQiCiIjNzE5IiwiQ29ubmVjdGVkIiwiY29t cGxldGVkIiwiMTRzZWMiLCIiLCJEaXJlY3QiLCIiLCJMaXZlIiwiMiIsIis5MTc4Mzc1NzU0MjQi LCJWaW5heSBLdW1hciIsIiIsIiIsIiIsIiIsIjE0cyIsIjE0cyIsIjI3LTEyLTIwMTgiLCIwNzoy MTowOCIsIiIsIiIsIiIsIiIsIiIsIiIsIiIsIiIsIiIsIjI3IERlYyAyMDE4IDA3OjIxIHBtIiwi Igo= --rel-732f894bea31c14ce42d0ab7d93adc77-- --732f894bea31c14ce42d0ab7d93adc77-- )

Comment: Please check attachment file path, it must be correct. According your code you have used website url path but you have to use your server related path path, For this thing you can check this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10045719/how-do-i-send-an-email-with-an-attachment-in-cakephp-2-0

Check the documentation 
https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/email.html#sending-attachments